# Why does local training with Google AI-Platform not work in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-sdk, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am using AI-platform from the Google Cloud Platform to train a Random Forest Classifier with scikit-learn using [this template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/sklearn/sklearn-template/template) from the Google Cloud Platform GitHub.

I have adjusted the code in some places to fit my own problem. The code is written in Python 3.5, using PyCharm and on an Ubuntu device. Training the model in the cloud works perfectly fine using the following terminal [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training) (excluding the additional arguments):

```sh
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training
```

But when I am trying to use the [local training functionality](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/local/train) of ai-platform inside my virtual environment (python 3.5):

```sh
gcloud ai-platform local train
```

(excluding the additional arguments). It returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/99/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/99/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/merijn/PycharmProjects/user-matching/trainer/task.py", line 28, in <module>
    from trainer import model
  File "trainer/model.py", line 28, in <module>
    from trainer import utils
  File "trainer/utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow import gfile
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

All the dependencies are properly installed within my virtual environment, including TensorFlow. Before the TensorFlow import error, it was an sklearn import error, which I solved by installing the sklearn module in my normal environment. This supports my guess that it probably has to do with the Google SDK running on python 2.7 in my normal environment. So when running the `gcloud` command within my venv, it most likely runs my whole program in my normal environment instead of my venv and so far I am unable force it to run in my venv. Note that I have already tried many different values for the arguments `--job-dir` and `--package-path`.

After days of searching the internet I still can't find a way to locally train with AI-platform in a virtual environment with python 3.5 installed. Hopefully you can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. It has to do with gcloud being unable to execute Python3 programs locally.

A very simple workaround exists -- don't use `gcloud ai-platform local train`.
Instead, just call the python interpreter directly:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/some/dir/package/path
python3 -m trainer.task --job-dir /tmp ...
```